# Is there a more Pythonic way to conditionally merge adjacent list elements?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following list.

```
myList = ["echo FooBar \\", "and some more foos", "cat /etc/cpuinfo", 
    "cat /path/to/\\", "long/deep/directory/\\", "that/goes/on/forever"]
```

I want to merge any element that ends in a `\` with the element on its right, removing the `\` in the process, and continue to do this until there are no more elements with a trailing `\`.

The correct output looks like this.

```
['echo FooBar and some more foos', 
 'cat /etc/cpuinfo', 
 'cat /path/to/long/deep/directory/that/goes/on/forever']
```

Here is my current solution, which is functional but seems much more complex than necessary.

```
myList = ["echo FooBar \\", "and some more foos", "cat /etc/cpuinfo", 
    "cat /path/to/\\", "long/deep/directory/\\", "that/goes/on/forever"]

tmpItem = None
tmpList = []

for x in myList:
   if tmpItem:
     if tmpItem.endswith("\\"):
        tmpItem = tmpItem[:-1] + x
     else:
        tmpList.append(tmpItem)
        tmpItem = x
   else: tmpItem = x

if tmpItem:
     if tmpItem.endswith("\\"):
        tmpList.append(tmpItem[:-1])
     else:
        tmpList.append(tmpItem)

print tmpList
```

**Is there a more concise way to do this in Python, possibly using a more functional idiom?**

I looked at [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), but it seems to only let you move a reduce from a list to a single element, rather than to another list, but perhaps I am underestimating its power.

Comment: That code seems to be the only reasonable way to do it. I would hope that any other way would be just more convoluted.

Comment: does your code work? If two sequential items end with `\\` do three items get concatenated?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if more pythonic, but certainly more concise.

```
"\0".join(myList).replace("\\\0","").split("\0")
```

If you can't make assumptions that the strings don't include `\0` you can generate the separator:

```
import string
import random
sep = ""
while any(sep in s for s in myList):
    sep += random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
sep.join(myList).replace("\\"+sep,"").split(sep)
```

Comment: Nice, you can also use a more "rare" symbol, like `\0`.

Comment: That's still inherently flawed - introducing an arbitrary limitation.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev That's true. I added an alternative solution that can be used if `\0` can be included in input.

Comment: Flawed it may be, but still a very creative and useful solution for a large subset of the problem.

Comment: I love when people state how bad an answer is but give no suggestions on how to fix it nor pose another solution.

Comment: @SethMMorton a better solution is already present so I upvoted it instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = ["echo FooBar \\", "and some more foos", "cat /etc/cpuinfo", 
    "cat /path/to/\\", "long/deep/directory/\\", "that/goes/on/forever"]
ret = []
for i in myList:
    if ret and ret[-1].endswith('\\'):
        ret[-1] = ret[-1][:-1] + i
    else:
        ret.append(i)

print ret
```

prints

```
['echo FooBar and some more foos', 'cat /etc/cpuinfo',
 'cat /path/to/long/deep/directory/that/goes/on/forever']
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is pythonic for you:

```
reduce(lambda agg, x: (agg +
                        [agg.pop()[:-1] + x] if agg[-1].endswith('\\') else
                         agg + [x]) if len(agg) > 0 else
                         agg + [x], myList, [])
```

I think it's cool and useful to understand (even if not to use)

Explanation: uses the aggregated list in `reduce` and looks back to the last element to append to it if needed. Otherwise appends to list. Doesn't look back on first element to avoid exception.

> ['echo FooBar and some more foos', 'cat /etc/cpuinfo', 'cat /path/to/long/deep/directory/that/goes/on/forever']

Comment: A few new lines would make it easier to read (without scrolling)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it properly in SO.

Answer (score 0):

A possibly easier to read solution is

```
wp = 0
for L in myList:
    if wp and myList[wp - 1].endswith('\\'):
        myList[wp - 1] = myList[wp - 1][:-1] + L
    else:
        myList[wp] = L
        wp += 1
del myList[wp:]
```

For me this is easier to read because the `wp` "write-pointer" pattern to modify arrays inplace is something that I've in the fingers. Readiility is in the eye of the beholder...

A purely functional solution (no assignments at all) could be

```
def merge_continuations(L, ix=0):
    if ix >= len(L)-1:
        return L
    elif L[ix].endswith('\\'):
        return merge_continuations(L[:ix] +
                                   [L[ix][:-1] + L[ix+1]] +
                                   L[ix+2:], ix)
    else:
        return merge_continuations(L, ix+1)
```

but it really doesn't belong to Python.

Another version could be written as a generator, accepting any iterable:

```
def merge_continuations(it):
    prefix = None
    for L in it:
        if prefix is None:
            prefix = L
        elif prefix.endswith('\\'):
            prefix = prefix[:-1] + L
        else:
            yield prefix
            prefix = L
    if prefix is not None:
        yield prefix
```

not my preferred approach, but idiomatic in Python

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the shortest, but it's fairly readable and Pythonic.

```
out, grp = [], []
for s in my_list:
    if s.endswith('\\'):
        grp.append(s[:-1])
    else:
        out.append(''.join(grp) + s)
        grp = []

print(out)
```