# Can not do in place sort and assigned to a variable in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have one basic Question in python:
I want to sort a list and assigned to variable using list.sort(). It does not seem to work why?

```
Q2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25]
Q3 = Q2.sort()
Q3 # prints nothing
```

I wonder why it is so though the Q2 get sorted already if I print Q2
Thanks.

Comment: Be careful! Lists are `mutable` ! that means, that if you use then `sort()` method, you are touching the list itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is in-place and does not return anything. You'd have to use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) which sorts and returns a copy of the sorted list, but will leave Q2 unmodified.

```
>>> Q3 = sorted(Q2)
>>> Q3
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 9, 16, 25]
```

`sort` is just meant to be called to sort the list without having to make a copy

```
>>> Q2.sort()
>>> Q2
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: sorted returns a sorted list? I have come across sorted fun. Before sorted fun was added people used to sort it then assign ? Thanks.

Comment: *"sorted returns a sorted list"* Yes, look at the example I just showed. If you want to assign to another variable, you have to use `sorted` because `sort` returns `None`

Comment: Thanks. But what I wondered was, how people did it before sorted was added in python 2.4(maybe).

Comment: You could do it in two steps then. You would first call `Q2.sort()` then assign `Q3 = Q2` or just use `Q2` directly.

Comment: @juggernaut You'd first copy the list, then sort. `Q3 = list(Q2)` then `Q3.sort()`. That's essentially what `sorted()` does.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on it to be in place you could do this:

```
Q3 = "lolz" if Q2.sort() else Q2
```

But I don't see the point of it :)

you should be using `sorted(Q2)` which returns a sorted list.

Comment: Thanks. This is a wonderful community and very smart programmers. It was my first post. Also very quick responses.

Comment: If I were new to Python and read this response, I'd be really, really confused... and I might actually your suggestion because I wouldn't know any better. Joke responses are funny, but sometimes newbies don't get the joke.

Comment: Actually my comments was so because I was reading stackoverflow for past 6 months and responses and alternatives provided by the community for a question is something I have not seen else where. It's beautiful.

Comment: @jme It's not **only** a joke. If for some reason you need to sort the list in place and do it in a functional way - this is a way to do it. Let's say in a list comprehension, or in a `reduce`... Obviously understanding the code you are using is important.

Comment: Do you have an example of this "trick" in non-trivial code? If you say it has value then I believe you, but I can't say I've ever felt the need for it. Mutation and functional coding don't normally mix well.

Comment: I don't have this exactly, but here is an answer I gave just now that needs to mutate (`pop` from) a list in a `reduce` call : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462827/is-there-a-more-pythonic-way-to-conditionally-merge-adjacent-list-elements/27463161#27463161